# How to enable the top and right spines of a FacetGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, catplot

I tried using `sns.set_style("white")`, but the spines only cover the bottom and left side. How can I set the spines all around the figure?

I also tried `plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.1, top=0.1)` to see if the spines were just hidden by the size, but I got a message that left and bottom needs to be bigger than right and top.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) automatically "despines" its figures, but you can disable this behavior using the `facet_kws` parameter:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.catplot(data=df, x="age", y="class", facet_kws={"despine": False})
```

[image]